# 'EOF within quoted string' warning when using read.delim

Tags: r

I'm a beginner to R, and I'm trying to read a zipped .tsv file in R for analysis, but I am having trouble reading the whole file.
The script I used is written by the data providers, so I guess it should be the right code, but I get a message that says

```
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec, :EOF within quoted string
```

and I can only see 6,017,494 out of 7,430,874 lines of the data.

The script is as follows:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(data.table)
#TODO: change directory as needed
setwd("directory")
```

```r
data<- read.delim(unz("patent.tsv.zip", "patent.tsv"), header=TRUE, sep ="\t", comment.char="#",  stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote="\"", fill = TRUE)
```

I looked up some questions on the EOF warning, and some suggested setting `quote=""`, and I tried it but then it just takes forever to read the data. I guess it doesn't work in my case because the quote is already set to `"\""`? Not sure what that means though.. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Could you try with the `readr` library. It is often more robust and faster than the basic `read.delim` provided in R. [Here](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) is the same function within `readr` library. If you still have the error, you are right, it is highly probable that the error comes from quotes.

Comment: I tried the 'readr' library and it is definitely faster, but it keeps stuck at about 97%, and shows an error message about memory usage. I think my RAM is not big enough to fit the whole dataset. Is there a parameter in the readr library that allows me to read just the first few thousand rows of the data? I couldn't find one on the description page.

Comment: Yes, you can use the argument `n_max` to limit the number of rows you want to read. It is in the documentation [here](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html).